# logstash grok filter pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

This is my log files.

```
Application-log-sample.log

2017-01-03 05:40:49.693 INFO  main --- com.getsentry.raven.DefaultRavenFactory : Using an HTTP connection to Sentry.
2017-01-03 05:40:49.935 INFO  background-preinit --- org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version : HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
```

I am getting confuse for grok pattern. Can you someone please suggest something.

Comment: You can use [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to create Grok Pattern for your log. Check available grok pattern constant 
 [here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#) . You can also write your own pattern and define it under `pattern.d`.

Answer (score 2):

a simple pattern could be:

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:event_time}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s+%{SYSLOGPROG}\s---\s%{JAVACLASS:class}\s+:\s+%{GREEDYDATA:message}$
```

use https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to build your pattern and http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match to test it on many lines.

you can also configure grok to check multiple patterns (stops at first matched) and to use your own patterns, see [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check your grok pattern is working correct or not without running the configuration file by grok debugger. Here is the link for grok debugger,

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com

Grok discover will help you to achieve the pattern which ever you needed.